# App crashes, NSInvalidLayoutConstraintException, red exclamation in iOS storyboard designer ViewController

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, crash, storyboard

Two main issues, which may be related:

1. Mobile app is crashing immediately after launch screen. May be due to a UI problem.
2. In the storyboard designer, a `ViewController` (only 1) is not scaling when a different screen size is selected, and has a red exclamation point.

I recently updated Xamarin.iOS in Visual Studio for Mac to accommodate Apple's iOS 11.3 and Xcode 9.3 updates, and my app crashes immediately after launching (launch screen appears, then app crashes & closes). I can't find any error messages in the output / console.

On my Main.Storyboard, there is a red exclamation mark in the lower right corner of my main `ViewController`. Clicking this reveals the following `NSInvalidLayoutConstraintException` error details: 
[image: Foundation.MonoTouchException was thrown.]

Also, when I change the "Viewing: iPhone [various versions]" to change the preview screen size of each ViewController's UI, this same `ViewController` that has the red exclamation mark retains all of it's elements squished in the iPhone SE layout. That is, when I select "iPhone 8 Plus" for example, the elements don't expand to fill the entire `ViewController`, while other ViewControllers have no issues expanding: 
[image: iPhone SE vs iPhone 8 Plus]

I don't see any problematic constraints - I've gone over each constraint in Document Outline - none seem to be referencing erroneously. I've heard you can accidentally reference incompatible constraints, like `label.X` to a another `UIView.Y`... Yet when dragging / creating a constraint some lines appear as dotted and red, not allowing the [incompatible?] constraint to be made.

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The constraint causing the red exclamation mark AS WELL AS causing the app to crash was somewhat defined in the `NSInvalidLayoutConstraintException` error, top-right line. It doesn't give the name of the element upon which the constraint is defined, but it says:

> .....'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top == UIView:......leading + 20

and with that I was able to narrow down which constraint it was in Document Outline. I don't know HOW I managed to tie a .top to a .leading, but it was there.

Hope this helps someone! I Spent several days trying to fix it! :-G |-{ Cheers!